# Ruby Escaping Arguments Inside Backticks Shell

Tags: ruby, shell, process, escaping

I'm wanting to throw a Ruby variable filled with an HTML file that I have grabbed with open-uri and nokogiri, into a backticks system process to tidy it up.  The nature of the variable is confusing the process.  I am thinking I need to escape it but I am not sure.  Any advice appreciated.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.wikihow.com/Bathe-a-Cat'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
pagestring = page.to_s

result = `tidy --break-before-br no --char-encoding utf8 --clean yes --drop-empty-paras yes ' #{pagestring}'`
puts results.length
```

Here is the error I get:

```
sh: -c: line 144: syntax error near unexpected token `"Search","Search","Custom_search"'
sh: -c: line 144: `    <input type="submit" id="cse_sa" value="Search" class="search_button" onmouseover="button_swap(this);" onmouseout="button_unswap(this);" onclick='gatTrack("Search","Search","Custom_search");'>'
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use IO.popen instead. Then you can invoke the command with an array instead of stringifying it:

```
cmd = %w{ tidy --break-before-br no --char-encoding utf8 --clean yes --drop-empty-paras yes }
result = IO.popen(cmd, 'r+') {|io| 
  io.puts pagestring
  io.close_write
  io.read
}
```

assuming `tidy` reads HTML from stdin.

Comment: Excellent.  Worked like a charm.  I've never used this before, and I assumed the backticks would be the solution.  I'm new to Ruby.  Thanks for your input, guys!

Answer (score 2):

For normal arguments like file paths and stuff like that, you could use `"str".shellescape` (http://apidock.com/ruby/Shellwords/shellescape).

```
args_array = [ ... ]
`tidy #{args_array.map(&:shellescape).join(' ')`
```

However, to pass a complete html file as an command line argument, something like what was suggested above might be better. I just though I'd mention this here for reference to others for normal cli arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dumping all that HTML onto the command line, why not make a file?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'tempfile'

url = 'http://www.wikihow.com/Bathe-a-Cat'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
pagestring = page.to_s

file = Tempfile.new('blah')
file.write(pagestring)
file.close

result = `tidy --break-before-br no --char-encoding utf8 --clean yes --drop-empty-paras yes #{file.path}`
puts result.length

file.unlink
```

Seems to work with a quick test here...

Comment: Because I don't want any files made.  This is a hook I'm writing to get "current Safari URL" into BBEdit without any files.  The process is called manually and I need zero footprint.  On the way to BBEdit, I thought I'd clean up the HTML for viewing, which is the overall goal of doing all this.

Comment: Sorry...I had originally thought that I might have to make a file, but just tossing data around is just fine for this, if not preferred.